# I want to extract all <li> element text that are under <ul>

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, css-selectors

I need to click on all elements BASIC, TRACKS, ...
My idea is to extract all elements in list then using list count and loop, I'll click on each and every element.
Need to check that each and every element is working even if new element is added I don't want to check code.

```html
<div class="headerarea" style="" xpath="1">
                    <h2>
                        <span id="ctl00_ctl00_phDesktop_lblModuleTitle">Abstract Setup</span>
                    </h2>
                    
                            <ul>
                        
                            <li>
                                <a id="ctl00_ctl00_phDesktop_rModuleNavigation_ctl01_btnModuleNavigation" class="headerarea_active" href="https://staging.m-anage.com/Modules/Abstract/Setup/basics.aspx">Basic</a></li>
                            
                        
                            <li>
                                <a id="ctl00_ctl00_phDesktop_rModuleNavigation_ctl02_btnModuleNavigation" href="https://staging.m-anage.com/testselenium/en-US/Abstract/AbstractSetup/Tracks">Tracks</a></li>
                            
                        
                            <li>
                                <a id="ctl00_ctl00_phDesktop_rModuleNavigation_ctl03_btnModuleNavigation" href="https://staging.m-anage.com/Modules/Abstract/Setup/steps.aspx">WIZARD</a></li>
                            
                        
                            <li>
                                <a id="ctl00_ctl00_phDesktop_rModuleNavigation_ctl04_btnModuleNavigation" href="https://staging.m-anage.com/Modules/Abstract/Setup/keywords.aspx">KEYWORDS</a></li>
                            
                        
                            <li>
                                <a id="ctl00_ctl00_phDesktop_rModuleNavigation_ctl05_btnModuleNavigation" href="https://staging.m-anage.com/Modules/Abstract/Setup/categories.aspx">CATEGORIES</a></li>
                            
                        
                            <li>
                                <a id="ctl00_ctl00_phDesktop_rModuleNavigation_ctl06_btnModuleNavigation" href="https://staging.m-anage.com/Modules/Abstract/Setup/conditions.aspx">CONDITIONS</a></li>
                            
                        
                            <li>
                                <a id="ctl00_ctl00_phDesktop_rModuleNavigation_ctl07_btnModuleNavigation" href="https://staging.m-anage.com/Modules/Abstract/Setup/interests.aspx">Interests</a></li>
                            
                        
                            <li>
                                <a id="ctl00_ctl00_phDesktop_rModuleNavigation_ctl08_btnModuleNavigation" href="https://staging.m-anage.com/Modules/Abstract/Setup/templates.aspx">Templates</a></li>
                            
                        
                            <li>
                                <a id="ctl00_ctl00_phDesktop_rModuleNavigation_ctl09_btnModuleNavigation" href="https://staging.m-anage.com/testselenium/en-US/Abstract/AbstractSetup/Index">Submission fee</a></li>
                            
                        
                            <li>
                                <a id="ctl00_ctl00_phDesktop_rModuleNavigation_ctl10_btnModuleNavigation" href="https://staging.m-anage.com/testselenium/en-US/Mail/MailServerSetup/Index?pModuleType=Abstract" style="">SMTP Setup</a></li>
                            
                        
                            <li>
                                <a id="ctl00_ctl00_phDesktop_rModuleNavigation_ctl11_btnModuleNavigation" href="https://staging.m-anage.com/testselenium/en-US/Abstract/AbstractSetup/Coauthor">Co-author</a></li>
                            
                        
                            </ul>
                        
                </div>
```

[I tried travelling to child path but no success](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ll4Ct.jpg)

Here is the java code that I tried.

```
    List<WebElement> tags = 
          driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='headerarea']/ul/li")); 
    for(int i=0;i<tags.size();i++) { 
       while(???) { 
        
     //driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='headerarea']/ul/li")).click(); 
         }
    }
```

Comment: Where is your code?

Comment: List<WebElement>  tabs= driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("//div[@class='headerarea'].h2"));

I'm not sure what code you are talking about.



@JaSON

Comment: Yes, your Java code. Update your question with the code and error trace

Comment: List<WebElement> tags = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='headerarea']/ul/li"));
  
  for(int i=0;i<tags.size();i++)
  {
   
  while(???)
  {
   //driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='headerarea']/ul/li")).click();
  }
  
  }      @JaSON

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below code :

```
List<WebElement> links = driver.findElements(By.tagName("li"));
for (int i = 1; i < links.size(); i++)
{
    System.out.println(links.get(i).getText());
}
```

You can also use `WebDriverWait` if you are facing synchronization issue.

```
 WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
 List<WebElement> links = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.tagName(li)));
 for (int i = 1; i < links.size(); i++)
 {
  System.out.println(links.get(i).getText());
 }
```

Comment: I'm able to extract text but when I try to click on each and every element it gives error.

org.openqa.selenium.StaleElementReferenceException: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document (Session info: chrome=84.0.4147.89) For documentation on this error, please visit: seleniumhq.org/exceptions/stale_element_reference.html Build

Comment: That means your DOM ref is no longer valid. When you are trying to perform action next time on your element that element no longer attached to the DOM. try to refresh your reference, or in real world terms find the element again

Answer (score 0):

```
List<WebElement> tags = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(".headerarea ul>li")); 
for(WebElement e : tags) {
    e.click();
}
```

Comment: Yes I tried this but getting error so tried using count.
org.openqa.selenium.StaleElementReferenceException: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
  (Session info: chrome=84.0.4147.89)
For documentation on this error, please visit: https://www.seleniumhq.org/exceptions/stale_element_reference.html
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.